SSR Angular handle static json asset that generates routerLinks
I am working on a page that utilizes the Anuglar SSR functionality. It is a static page so there is no server that communicates with it.
I request a json asset on a page that contains information on what routes are available and builds [routerLink] elements based on it.
@for (post of filteredPosts; track $index) {
  <!-- This element contains a routerLink that uses information from the postData -->
  <stars-blog-post-card [postData]="post"></stars-blog-post-card>
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.handleSeo();
    this.blogPostDataClientService.getBlogPostData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.posts = data.filter((post) => post.published);

      ...

      this.filteredPosts = this.posts;

      // We use OnPush change detection
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }

I think there is a problem with this approach when it comes to web crawlers. The elements are only visible after successfully transfering the asset json file. Correct me if I am wrong on this, please!
Is there a way to populate routes build from asset information in the preload stage so that webcrawlers can see the elements? If not would it be better to create an entry in the sitemap.xml for every subpage?
With this current approach the page is rendered after receiving the asset as expected. I tried to manually include the json file in the code instead of transfering it, but I am not sure if this is best practice or changes anything.

You are looking for Prerendering (SSG) where you can try out different options like

discoverRoutes - Whether the builder should process the Angular Router configuration to find all unparameterized routes and prerender them.

routesFile - The path to a file that contains a list of all routes to prerender, separated by newlines. This option is useful if you want to prerender routes with parameterized URLs.


I guess you might need option 2 since it might be a parameterized route.
But the gist is configure this so that the content is prerendered and the web crawlers are able to see the contents

Thank you for this answer! I think this does not help me. With my current approach, the main problem lays in the [routerLink] elements not being present before receiving the asset data.
When going with an approach like this, I could also change the sitemap.xml to include the elements, but I am searching for something more dynamic if possible.

@stars when you ssg the routes will be available because angular generates static content after fetching the json during ng build
